# Obfuscate or obscure a password

Tags: word-choice

Passwords are often replaced with dots or asterisk characters.

[image: password replaced with dots]

Which of the following is more idiomatic?

- to *obscure* a password
  or
- to *obfuscate* a password

Online examples include:

> **Obscuring Passwords and Keys** ...

[[Dell Technologies](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-uk/networking-z9100/z9100-on-9.14.2.8-config-pub/obscuring-passwords-and-keys?guid=guid-c1339ca6-18fb-4d70-ade8-4babcadf4b30&lang=en-us)]

> **Obfuscating passwords**
>
> You should obfuscate the SSL connector keystore password for greater
> security. ...  Specifying the passwords as clear text is not
> recommended because they are not secure. Instead, you should obfuscate
> the passwords so that they are not easily read....

[[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35822_01/server.740/es_admin/src/tadm_ssl_jetty_passwords.html)]

*If there is an even better term please add it :)*

Comment: I'd think the most common term in everyday English would be "hide".

Comment: "Obfuscate" is almost certainly wrong. Obfuscation is the process of overlaying comparatively simple information or procedures by unnecessarily complex language or processes. If one is trying legitimately to secure sensitive information then "obscuring" (or "hiding" as @KillingTime said) that information would be the right word.

Comment: Hello, Haphil. When you say 'These are the terms I found,' what exactly do you mean? For instance: (a) Did you find them in a dictionary, a thesaurus, in blogs ...? (b) Did you find the string 'obfuscate a password' or merely the word 'obfuscate'?

Comment: @BoldBen I'd argue that "obfuscate" is not definitively wrong, just a bit off. The definition you give for it is one meaning, but one could also obfuscate purposefully for beneficial purposes. The key distinction seems to me that it tends to be used of concepts (one obfuscates a *meaning*), while "obscure" can be used literally of blocking visibility (as well as figuratively).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth (a) no, I could not find any thesaurus that gave me a connection from obfuscate/obscure to password. Therefore the question here. Guess I could have mentioned that. (b) the string as a whole, e.g. in oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35822_01/server.740/es_admin/src/tadm_ssl_jetty_passwords.html
(c)And what I meant by it: I searched for words that may fit in the dictionary and then cross checked those 2 (among some others) in the thesaurus - regarding "hide" - it seemed too broad for me at first sight; so I didn't consider it.

Comment: What did a thesaurus suggest for obfuscate or obscure or hide?

Comment: Come on now, folks. obfuscate is used for arguments or opinions and that sort of thing. obfuscate is not used for things like passwords. Geesus.

Comment: In the Dell case, the doc is talking about obscuring (masking) the output display of the encrypted password, but the Oracle doc is talking about embedding an obfuscated password into a configuration/code file. Code obfuscation for security is like the Club on your steering wheel to prevent car theft.  To see excellent examples of code obfuscation (render obscure, unclear, or unintelligible), look at these entries: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/307/obfuscated-hello-world . All these do are essentially print "Hello World".

Comment: @AndyBonner You're probably right, but in normal usage I think of "obfuscate" as relating to complex or abstract concepts (like opinons or procedures) rather than simple things like passwords. In fact Oracle's use of "obfuscate" to describe the concealing of a password sounds like obfuscation to me! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Password masking** seems to be the usual term, so if you want a verb it would be to **mask a password**.

From security expert [Bruce Schneier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Schneier)'s [blog](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2017/07/password_maskin.html): "Slashdot asks if password masking — replacing password characters with asterisks as you type them — is on the way out."

Also, [Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/password-masking-hurt-signup-form/), [Apache documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/masking-passwords), [Major Geeks](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_show_hidden_or_masked_passwords_behind_asterisks.html), an article on [Medium](https://medium.com/@yulianaz/better-password-masking-for-sign-up-forms-eedbef09b657)  called "Passport 'masking' vs 'unmasking'", and plenty more if you Google.

The word "hiding"/"hidden"/"hide" is also used quite commonly, but is less specific.